# Single IP multiple domains SSL issue

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, https

I've just noticed a small problem with a self signed SSL I am using for a webmail subdomain on one of my domains.

I was using https://webmail.website0.com just to secure it a bit but I've noticed that if I visit https://website1.com https://website2.com etc they all point to the webmail website. Is this normal? Can I avoid it somehow?

All the websites are sharing the same IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal - by default all websites sharing an IP address will be pulled up if going to https://anydomainthatsharesthatip.com.  The reason why is that SSL is at a level before HTTP header communication so all Apache has to go on at that stage of the request is the IP address and port being requested (i.e. it hasn't received the HTTP `Host:` header yet).

There is a newer standard known as SNI which supports sending the `Host:` header earlier, but the most typical way to avoid this is to give website0.com a dedicated IP and problem's solved.  You could somewhat avoid it by creating a :443 VirtualHost later in the conf file which use website0's SSL certificate but which has website1.com, website2.com, etc. as ServerName / ServerAlias directives, but if people go to https://website1.com, they'll see website0's SSL certificate; however, website1 will be pulled up instead as expected.